# Фильтр и калькулятор для нескольких блоков jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, калькулятор, фильтр

Есть слайдер выбора диапазона, который подставляет значение в инпут и в соответствующее поле на карточке оффера.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я смогла написать код, который просчитывает сумму выплаты, учитывая ставку, однако это работает только для одного блока. Калькулятор берет последнее значение ставки и подставляет везде. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы в каждом блоке все просчитывалось отдельно?

```
 $('.sum-input').text(inp.val());
        inp.change (function() {
                var result = $('.result');
                var comissionSpan = $('.comission');
                var percents = +$('.percents').text();
                var zaim = +inp.val();
                var comission = zaim/100*percents*30;
                var resultVal = zaim+comission;
                $('.sum-input').text(inp.val());
                $(comissionSpan).text(comission);
                $(result).text(resultVal);
          });
```

Также нужно, чтобы блоки фильтровались относительно суммы займа. То есть если сумма займа 16000, то должны показываться только те офферы, в которых максимальная сумма займа >= 16000. Пыталась сделать таким образом, но это работает не так, как нужно

```
 var maxSum = +$('.max-sum').text();
     $('.offer').fadeOut(0);
     var count = 20;
     for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      $('.max-sum').filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() >= inp.val();
      }).parentsUntil(".offers").fadeIn(0);
     }
```

Вот html код одного оффера

```html
<div class="offer" id="1" style="border-color:#000">
 <div class="offer_feature">
  <span style="background-color:#000">
   Dinero
  </span>
 </div>
 <div class="offer_logo">
  <div class="offer_logo_con">
   <img src="img/dinero.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="offer_rating">
   <div class="offer_rating_stars">
    <div class="offer_rating_stars_icons">
     <i class="icon_star"></i>
     <i class="icon_star"></i>
     <i class="icon_star"></i>
     <i class="icon_star"></i>
     <i class="icon_star"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="offer_rating_stars_icons_outline">
     <i class="icon_star_outline"></i>
     <i class="icon_star_outline"></i>
     <i class="icon_star_outline"></i>
     <i class="icon_star_outline"></i>
     <i class="icon_star_outline"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="offer_info">
  <div class="offer_info_con">
   <div class="offer_money">
    <div>
     <div class="label">К выплате <br> за 30 дней</div>
     <div class="value result">
      <small>грн</small>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div>
     <div class="label">Сумма займа</div>
     <div class="value sum-input">
      <small>грн</small>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div>
     <div class="label">Комиссия</div>
     <div class="value ">
      <span class="comission"></span><small>грн</small>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="offer_conditions">
    <div>
     <div class="label">Займ</div>
     <div class="value">
      300-<span class="max-sum">15 000</span> <small>грн</small>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div>
     <div class="label">Ставка</div>
     <div class="value ">
      <span class="percents">0</span> <small>% в день</small>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div>
     <div class="label">Срок</div>
     <div class="value">
      7-30 <small>дней</small>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="offer_open">
   <a onclick="dinero()" target="_blank" class="btn primary_btn"
    style="cursor: pointer;">Оформить заявку</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не совсем понял, что надо сделать. Разместите пример вашего оффера в снипет

Comment: @doox911 Добавила html код, там в первую очередь непонятно, как сделать калькулятор. Он считает правильно, но подставляет одинаковые значения во все офферы. На картинке видно, что комиссия у Dinero и Mycredit получается одинаковая, хотя процентная ставка у них разная. Получается калькулятор просчитывает все для последнего оффера и подставляет эти значения везде

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы в каждом блоке все просчитывалось
>      отдельно?

Вот так должно работать:

```
$('.sum-input').text(inp.val());
inp.change (function() {
    $('.sum-input').text(inp.val()); // вынесено из перебора, т.к. это значение у всех одинаковое
    $('.offer').each(function(){ // перебор по всем .offer
        var result = $(this).find('.result'); // $(this) - это текущий .offer в переборе среди всех оферов
        var comissionSpan = $(this).find('.comission');
        var percents = +$(this).find('.percents').text();
        var zaim = +inp.val();
        var comission = zaim/100 * percents * 30;
        var resultVal = zaim + comission;
        comissionSpan.text(comission);
        result.text(resultVal);
    });
});
```

> 2. Также нужно, чтобы блоки фильтровались относительно суммы займа.

Попробуйте так:

```
$('.offer').fadeOut(0);
$('.offer').each(function(){
   if ($(this).find('.max-sum').eq(0).text() >= inp.val()) {
       $(this).fadeIn(0);
   }
});
```

Получилось? Если что-то не получилось, напишите что именно.

Comment: @EleneVasilenko Спасибо, все получилось) В фильтр еще добавила перевод значения inp.val() и max-sum в число, и все заработало